# Elementary proof for a generalized version of Pascal's hexagon theorem?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, alternative-proof, projective-geometry

I saw a generalization version of Pascal's theorem on a book, which is actually proved by deep algebraic geometry theorems (e.g., Cayley-Bacharach-Chasles theorem, or Bézout's theorem). I just wonder whether we can prove it by elementary/synthetic methods (e.g., perspective points, or invariance of cross-ratios and properties of second order point-rows)?

Given six points $A,B,C,D,E,F$ on a conic, we take another point $G$ and draw two conics, one (denoted as $a$) constructed from $A,B,G,E,F$ and another (denoted as $b$) from $B,C,D,G,E$. Two conics $a$ and $b$ intersect on four points $B,G,E,H$. Suppose $AF\cap CD=O$.

Prove: $G$, $O$ and $H$ are co-linear.

[image: Generalization of Pascal's theorem]

Comment: Nice question. There is some symmetry which allows to swap roles among the three conics. To show: $AF,CD,GH$ are concurrent.

Comment: Any ideas, @ccorn? For elementary proof, although it is similar configuration to Pascal, the cross-ratio proof of Pascal could not be applied due to lack of straight lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about synthetic proof but this theorem is the radical axis theorem, seen from a different projective point of view (I.e. Gaged differently). Extend this configuration from the real projective plane to the complex one. Then by applying a complex projective transformation, send the two points $B$ and $E$ to the two complex points at infinity $[1:i:0]$ and $[1:-i:0]$ respectively. Then the three conics on the picture get transformed into three conics from the pencil defined by $[1:i:0]$ and $[1:-i:0]$ which means they become three circles when we restrict ourselves back to the real projective plane. The three lines determined by pairwise intersecting conics are mapped to the radical axes of the three corresponding pairs of circles. By the radical axis "theorem" the three radical axes are concurrent.

Comment: Great answer! So we can project all graph with O as radical center of three circles by setting B and E as "circle points" on infinity line. Is it possible to generalize radical axis to general conics with similar properties like circle radical axes so that this problem could be proved easily as radical center theorem?

Comment: @user46090 Thank you for accepting my answer, although I have to admit I meant it as an extended comment, rather than an answer. But I guess, for now, we will do with what we have. Until a better answer shows up :)... With regards to a generalization of the radical axis, seems to me that in this case the fact that the three conics all pass through the same pair of points is crucial and that makes the other three lines radical axes. If one has a line formed by the intersection of only one pair of conics, seems to me that doesn't easily generalize to a radical axis.